# Regular expression match, extracting only wanted segments of string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract three segments from a string. As I am not particularly good with regular expressions, I think what I have done could probably be done better.

I would like to extract the bold parts of the following string:

> SOMETEXT: **ANYTHING_HERE** (Old=**ANYTHING_HERE**,
> New=**ANYTHING_HERE**)

Some examples could be:

> ABC: Some_Field (Old=,New=123)
>
> ABC:   Some_Field (Old=ABCde,New=1234)
>
> ABC: Some_Field (Old=Hello World,New=Bye Bye World)

So the above would return the following matches:

```
$matches[0] = 'Some_Field';
$matches[1] = '';
$matches[2] = '123';
```

So far I have the following code:

```
preg_match_all('/^([a-z]*\:(\s?)+)(.+)(\s?)+\(old=(.+)\,(\s?)+new=(.+)\)/i',$string,$matches);
```

The issue with the above is that it returns a match for each separate segment of the string. I do not know how to ensure the string is the correct format using a regular expression without catching and storing the match if that makes sense?

So, my question, if not already clear, how I can retrieve just the segments that I want from the above string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `preg_match_all`. You can use this `preg_match` call:

```
$s = 'SOMETEXT: ANYTHING_HERE (Old=ANYTHING_HERE1, New=ANYTHING_HERE2)';
if (preg_match('/[^:]*:\s*(\w*)\s*\(Old=(\w*),\s*New=(\w*)/i', $s, $arr))
   print_r($arr);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SOMETEXT: ANYTHING_HERE (Old=ANYTHING_HERE1, New=ANYTHING_HERE2
    [1] => ANYTHING_HERE
    [2] => ANYTHING_HERE1
    [3] => ANYTHING_HERE2
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is very helpful. One question I have, the SOMETEXT part can change as in it could be any text, but I do not want to capture it. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes sure, check the edit now. I am now using `[^:]+` to match whatever comes in place of `SOMETEXT`

Comment: What is the difference between `*` and `+`? How come your code above does not store the SOMETEXT part?

Comment: `*` means 0 or more matches and `+` means 1 or more matches

Comment: Yup, got it, makes much more sense now. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Also I updated my answer to use `*` every where to make sure it matches input like `'ABC: Some_Field (Old=,New=123)'`

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been at my computer for 10 hours or so... I wasn't aware that `preg_match()` creates and stores an array of matches, in that case, it is definitely not necessary to use `preg_match_all()` so thank you. I was going to accept this as the answer as 1) You were the first to answer 2) Your answer is correct 3) You have been extremely kind and helpful. However, the reason I accepted the other answer was merely because of the clear explanation he gave for every step in the regular expression. If in fact, you believe your answer is the correct one then I will of course change it. :-)

Comment: @BenCarey: I would never ask anybody to change the acceptance decision. It is OP's prerogative to accept any answer that works out best for him/her. My comment was more in context that if a working answer is already posted then there is no point in submitting same answer again (with some decorated text of course). Had you asked for explanation of regex I could have also provided same with some great online tutorials on regex like this http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Fair point, in that case I will accept your answer as you were the first one and you have been very helpful. In return, would you mind explaining what `\w` matches? One of the differences between your answer and the other one in question is that he uses `.*` (I know what this means). Furthermore, would you mind removing the downvote, if in fact it was you :-)

Comment: No I never downvoted your question but still went ahead and upvoted.

Comment: `\w` means any lower case or upper case letter i.e. `[a-z]` OR any digit `[0-9]` or underscore `_`

Comment: Talking about `.*` IMO it should be avoided in regex unless until it is necessary. If you notice I have used `\s*(\w*)\s*` which is better than using `\s*(.*)\s*`. Thank you very much for marking the answer as accepted. It is by no means end of our discussion. At any point if you run into doubts feel free to post a comment and I will respond back as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match_all('/([a-z]*)\:\s*.+\(Old=(.+),\s*New=(.+)\)/i',$string,$matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Example:

```
$string = 'ABC: Some_Field (Old=Hello World,New=Bye Bye World)';
```

Will match:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABC: Some_Field (Old=Hello World,New=Bye Bye World)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABC
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello World
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bye Bye World
        )

)
```

Comment: So does the `*` match but not capture? I think that is the character I needed I think

Comment: `*` is the same as `+` but can be empty. `a*` match `"aaaa"`, `"a"` and also an empty string `""`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using more parenthesis than you need, and thus capturing more segments of the input than you wish.

eg, each `(\s?)+` segment should just be `\s*`

The regex that you're looking for is:

```
[^:]+:\s*(.+)\s*\(old=(.*)\s*,\s*new=(.*)\)
```

In PHP:

```
preg_match_all('/[^:]+:\s*(.+)\s*\(old=(.*)\s*,\s*new=(.*)\)/i',$string,$matches);
```

A useful tool can be found here: http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

This tool offers an "Explain" checkbox (as well as a "PHP" checkbox and "i" flag checkbox which you'll want to select) which provides a full explanation of the regex as well. For posterity, I've included the explanation below as well:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?i-msx:                 group, but do not capture (case-insensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^:]+                    any character except: ':' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  old=                     'old='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  new=                     'new='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could you possibly change your answer so that the first match does not include the `:` and the space?

Comment: This answer's regex is almost identical to mine except that it was posted 5 minutes after my answer. Moreover it is using unnecessary `preg_match_all`

Comment: The `preg_match` vs `preg_match_all` is a fine point -- Ben, either will work, depending on whether you want to match one input set or multiple, respectively. And @anubhava, when multiple people are answering, sometimes you'll click submit first, while someone else is writing a longer explanation. There's nothing wrong with multiple similar answers -- generally it simply reinforces that the approach is sound. Thanks for pointing out the single vs multiple aspect of the matching options!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn Sorry for the delay, clearly on a different timezone... Your point about people taking longer to write answers is very valid and in this case it is the mere reason why I accepted yours. Whilst some of the other answers were correct, I felt yours was the most helpful because it includes a clear section by section explanation of how the regex works. If it had not been for that then I would have probably accepted anubhava's answer instead, simply because he was first. Thank you so much for all your help, really appreciate this! :-)

Answer (score 1):

What about something simpler like ^_^

```
[:=]\s*([\w\s]*)
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cV5kY8)

Comment: Two notes: (1) This misses the `Old=,` segment, and (2) this may be a shorter regex however it loses the result grouping. That is, given the OP's sample input, it generates 9 matches (technically 8 given the bug noted in point #1) rather than 3 groups of 3 matches -- the grouping of matches makes the results both more logically related to the input, as well as easier to debug for larger input.

Comment: Your regex does well but it's better to be `[:=]\s*([\w\s]*)`

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn, Indeed, personally I'd use your solution for more occuracy, I just tought this was another approach to go, but this fails if some values are missing... However, revo's tip corrects it, so it wasnt a waste of time afterall :)

Answer (score 0):

```
:\s*([^(\s]+)\s*\(Old=([^,]*),New=([^)]*)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/cS6uS0)

*also please tell if you want explanations.*

Comment: Note that this breaks on the first line of sample input: `ABC: Some_Field (Old=,New=123)`

Comment: (PS: Explanations should be assumed necessary, IMHO. The OP might follow, or they might only follow parts of the answer but not grok the full reason behind it. The more detail you can provide, the more generally helpful the answer will be for both the OP and for posterity.)

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn edited answer. Some OPs want more so I update my answer with details, but some just need the code so I'll go through simplicity.

Comment: Fixed regex noted, thanks. You should also update the demo link too, for posterity. And my point was that you're answering for both the OP and others who find the question down the road -- some may suss out the logic from the code itself, but others may need more info. The ideal answers on this site account for both a quick "here's the answer" intro, followed by a "here's why" explanation. :-)

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn always there are some users like you to explain more, so I keep my job as it's. ;-)